# telegram bot keeps replying rather than executing the following code (webhook is used)

Tags: http, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, webhooks

I am trying to host my telegram bot for a multiplayer game on GAE and web hook is used here. This is how my databasing part is like:

```
class Game(ndb.Model):
    chat_id = ndb.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    mission_num = ndb.IntegerProperty(default =1)
    round_num = ndb.IntegerProperty(default =1)

class Player(ndb.Model):
    user_id = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    player_role = ndb.StringProperty (
    choices = ['spy','resistance'])
```

The part of code under web hook handler:

```
        if text.startswith('/'):
        if text == '/start':
            reply('Bot enabled')
            setEnabled(chat_id, True)
        elif text == '/stop':
            reply('Bot disabled')
            setEnabled(chat_id, False)
        elif text == '/newgame':
            if chat_type == 'group':
                existing_game = Game.query (Game.chat_id == chat_id).get()
                if existing_game:
                    reply ("game is alr intitiated liao")
                else:
                    ##create a new game here 
                    #still stuck here 
                    ##========================##
                    #reply("keep replying this line")
                    ##========================##
                    new_game = Game (
                        chat_id = chat_id,
                        id = chat_id
                        )    
                    curr_game_key = new_game.put()

                    new_player = Player (
                        parent = curr_game_key,
                        user_id = fr_user_id,
                        id = fr_user_id)
                    new_player.put()
                    reply("waiting for more friends to join")
            else:
                reply('game must be conducted within a group chat! jio more friends!')
        else:
            reply('What command?')
    else:
        if getEnabled(chat_id):
            reply('I got your message! (but I do not know how to answer)')
        else:
            logging.info('not enabled for chat_id {}'.format(chat_id))
```

The problem is that when I send '/newgame' in a group chat, nothing is sent back to me. If I uncomment the following line my bot keeps sending me "keep replying this line" like crazy.:

```
#reply("keep replying this line")
```

The reply function:

```
def reply(msg=None, img=None):
        if msg:
            resp = urllib2.urlopen(BASE_URL + 'sendMessage', urllib.urlencode({
                'chat_id': str(chat_id),
                'text': msg.encode('utf-8'),
                'disable_web_page_preview': 'true',
                'reply_to_message_id': str(message_id),
            })).read()
        elif img:
            resp = multipart.post_multipart(BASE_URL + 'sendPhoto', [
                ('chat_id', str(chat_id)),
                ('reply_to_message_id', str(message_id)),
            ], [
                ('photo', 'image.jpg', img),
            ])
        else:
            logging.error('no msg or img specified')
            resp = None

        logging.info('send response:')
        logging.info(resp)
```

The error:

```
Internal Server Error
The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~orbitaltest2/1.393734187774164753/main.py", line 66, in get
    self.response.write(json.dumps(json.load(urllib2.urlopen(BASE_URL + 'getUpdates'))))
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 409: Conflict
```

code for the handler that line 66 belongs to:

```
class GetUpdatesHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(60)
        self.response.write(json.dumps(json.load(urllib2.urlopen(BASE_URL + 'getUpdates'))))
```

Totally newbie, any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check what status code & what content is returned by your webhook.

You have 2 options how to reply to use:

1. Call Telegram API
2. Return JSON as a response to webhook call

As you have not provided it source code of `reply()` it's hard to tell what exactly is wrong.

Anyway your webhook should return HTTP status code 200. If it does not Telegram treat it as an internal error and is trying to resent message to you. This is why you are getting repeated calls and it's "replying like crazy".

Most probably the call `reply("keep replying this line")` is successful but then something wrong and Telegram gets wrong reply.

Add `try/except` blocks and log exceptions.

Check your logs & put additional logging if needed. For example I'm logging HTTP response content from my webhook. It helps.

Comment: yea turns out the id i specified is too long when i look at the logs! thanks a lot!!!